# Shift the time in EXIF photo data

Tags: picasa, image-editing, exif, irfanview, exiftool

I need to shift the time data in a large number of photos, like adding 3 days and 3 hours to all of them.

- Is there any free tool that does this?
- Can any free image editors (like IrfanView) perform this task?

Searching online gives me one tool, [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/), it's a Perl program, a GUI exists.

Comment: So does ExifTool not work for you, or what's the problem?

Comment: Its doesn't support MP4 videos (the format used by my camera).

Comment: Otherwise its great, it can be downloaded as an executable, so its a bit easier to setup than I suspected.

Comment: In your question you didn't mention that you wanted to tag *videos*. Other than that, if ExifTool works for you, answer the question yourself, and you can even accept that!

Comment: Videoclips and photos comes together, so the ability to handle both is quite important.

Comment: (I think the title of this question is not the original one).

Comment: Actually the .THM-files (corresponding to each .MP4-file) are shifted, but they are not picked up by applicaations like Picasa